# socket.emit doesn't work inside setTimeout() nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, timer, socket.io

The first playerHandler.nextTurn() will return the first player from the player list with his corresponding socket id .But calling currsocket.emit won't do anything. I then tried io.emit which emits to all other players . Since I have max of 2 players , the event doesn't trigger inside the first player client socket. 
Calling the second player currsocket.emit would work properly . 
It seems there is some issue with the setTimeout() , since in my other code , this works without any issues (without timeout).

```
 socket.on('add-player', (player) => {
//console.log('socket add player hits');
console.log("add user name :" + player.name);
//add the new player
var newPlayer = { 'id': socket.id.toString(), 'name': player.name };
//dont use this. for the var declared above
var canWeKeepHim = { value: false };
var package = playerHandler.methods.addNewPlayer(newPlayer, canWeKeepHim);

//on successful addition of new player add him to gameroom socket room
if (canWeKeepHim.value) {
  socket.join('gameroom');
  console.log(player.name + 'joined socket room');
}

socket.emit('add-player-message', { type: 'success-message', package: package });
io.emit('add-player-list', playerHandler.methods.getNewPlayer());


//is the async nature of socket events a problem , the start-game never seems to be true;

if (GameHandler.currentGameState == GameHandler.yetToStartGame && playerHandler.methods.doWeHaveMaxPlayers()) {
  GameHandler.changeCurrentGameState(GameHandler.gameHasStarted);
  var delay = 3000;
  io.to('gameroom').emit('start-game', { value: true, delay: delay });
  //if the game state is still gameHasStarted after delay then fire the gameplay events
  GameHandler.gameArenaRedirectTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    if (GameHandler.currentGameState == GameHandler.gameHasStarted) {
      console.log('hey this works after 10s');
      var currentPlayerTurn = playerHandler.methods.nextTurn();
      currentPlayerTurn = playerHandler.methods.nextTurn();;
      var currsocket = io.sockets.sockets[currentPlayerTurn.id];
      currsocket.emit('next-turn', { myturn: true });
      //console.log(io.sockets.so)
      // io.emit('next-turn', { myturn: false, playerName: currentPlayerTurn.name });
      //io.to('gameroom').emit('next-turn', { myturn: false, playerName: currentPlayerTurn.name });
    }

  }, delay);

}
```

});

Comment: What's the difference between `socket.emit(...)` and `io.emit(...)`?

Comment: @PeterMader - `io.emit()` sends to all connected clients.  `socket.emit()` sends to one particular connected client.

Comment: Can you show more code context so we can see where `socket` is defined.

Comment: socket is argument when the client connects to the io . I used the basic code available in their website . io.on('connection', (socket) => { ... }

Answer (score 0):

I found out that moving the setTimeout out of the socket.on event listener callback and out of the io.on event listener fixed the issue.

```
function startCountDownToStartGame(callback, delay, arg) {
if (GameHandler.currentGameState == GameHandler.gameHasStarted) {
GameHandler.gameArenaRedirectTimer = setTimeout(callback, delay, arg);
 }

};
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
 console.log('user connected :' + socket.id);

 socket.on('disconnect', function () {
 console.log('user disconnected');
//TODO : remove player from the player list once hes disconnected
});

socket.on('add-player', (player) => {
//console.log('socket add player hits');
console.log("add user name :" + player.name);
//add the new player
var newPlayer = { 'id': socket.id.toString(), 'name': player.name };
//dont use this. for the var declared above
var canWeKeepHim = { value: false };
var package = playerHandler.methods.addNewPlayer(newPlayer, canWeKeepHim);

//on successful addition of new player add him to gameroom socket room
if (canWeKeepHim.value) {
  socket.join('gameroom');
  console.log(player.name + 'joined socket room');
}

socket.emit('add-player-message', { type: 'success-message', package: package });
io.emit('add-player-list', playerHandler.methods.getNewPlayer());

if (GameHandler.currentGameState == GameHandler.yetToStartGame && playerHandler.methods.doWeHaveMaxPlayers()) {
  GameHandler.changeCurrentGameState(GameHandler.gameHasStarted);
  var delay = 3000;
  io.to('gameroom').emit('start-game', { value: true, delay: delay });
  delay += 1000;// this is a temp fix
  //it seems calling the settimeout within the socket.on will somehow affect the emit functions for all other socket
  //other than the current socket , by placing the settimeout outside , it fixed the problem .
  startCountDownToStartGame((socket) => {
    var currentPlayerTurn = playerHandler.methods.nextTurn();
    var currsocket = io.sockets.sockets[currentPlayerTurn.id];
    currsocket.emit('next-turn', { myturn: true });
    currsocket.broadcast.to('gameroom').emit('next-turn', { myturn: false, playerName: currentPlayerTurn.name });
  }, delay, socket);

}



});

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try passing socket to your setTimout

```
  GameHandler.gameArenaRedirectTimer = setTimeout((socket) => {
        if (GameHandler.currentGameState == GameHandler.gameHasStarted) {
          console.log('hey this works after 10s');
          var currentPlayerTurn = playerHandler.methods.nextTurn();
          currentPlayerTurn = playerHandler.methods.nextTurn();;
          var currsocket = io.sockets.sockets[currentPlayerTurn.id];
          currsocket.emit('next-turn', { myturn: true });
          //console.log(io.sockets.so)
          // io.emit('next-turn', { myturn: false, playerName: currentPlayerTurn.name });
          //io.to('gameroom').emit('next-turn', { myturn: false, playerName: currentPlayerTurn.name });
        }

      }, delay,socket);
```

Comment: Isnt the socket passed as a callback parameter here , is it right ?

Comment: i hope so. did you try like this?

Comment: threw an error . timers.js:342
    throw new TypeError('"callback" argument must be a function');

Comment: I did try this , didnt work , I even passed in the server socket 'io' instance .Still doesnt work

Comment: did you console socket inside setTimeout? to check weather we are passing it correctly or not?

Comment: It seems out of the two players , only the first player socket events dont work . I think , the settimeout which is initiated after the second player joins(starts the game) takes only one instance ?

Comment: i didnt console log it , but calling io.emit will work only for the second player .